# How to get index of any charcter in unicode string

Tags: c#, string, unicode, utf-8

I having a string variable which basically holds value of corresponding **English** word in the form of **Chinese**.

```
 String temp = "'％1'不能输入步骤'％2'";
```

But when i want to know wether the string having %1 in it or not by using IndexOf function

```
      if(temp.IndexOf("%1") != -1)
{
}
```

I am not getting true even if it contain %1.

So is there any issue due to **Chinese** charters or any thing else.

Pls suggest me how i can get the index of any charter in above case.

Comment: `％` (fullwidth percent) is not the same character as `%` (regular percent sign), so that might be a problem right off the bat.

Comment: [`％`](http://www.decodeunicode.org/u+FF05) != [`%`](http://www.decodeunicode.org/u+0025) - they are different characters

Comment: I am not able to match % strings in different cultures

Comment: Culture has nothing to with it. You have two different characters that look like two circles separated by a diagonal line. Replace one of them with another, either manually or via normalization.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `％1` is not equal to `%1` What you want to do in this case as workaround is select the symbols out of string you have like

```
 var s = "'％1'不能输入步骤'％2'";
 var firstFragment = s.Substring(1, 2); // this should select you ％1
```

and then do

```
if(temp.IndexOf(first) != -1){

}
```

Comment: I am not able to match % strings in different cultures.

Answer (score 0):

Comments gave the answer. Use the same percent character, so instead of:

```
"%1"
```

use:

```
"％1"
```

Or, if you find that problematic (your source code is in a "poor" code page, or you fear the code is hard to read when it contains full-width characters that resemble ASCII characters), use:

```
"\uFF051"
```

or even:

```
"\uFF05" + "1"
```

(concatenation will be done by the C# compiler, no extra concatting done at run-time).

---

Another approach might be **Unicode normalization**:

```
temp = temp.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
```

which seems to project the "exotic" percent char into the usual ASCII percent char, although I am not sure if that behavior is guaranteed, but see the `Decomposition` field on [Unicode Character 'FULLWIDTH PERCENT SIGN' (U+FF05)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FF05/index.htm).

Comment: temp.Normalize is not working for me.
I am not able to match % strings in different cultures